# What is dom for in the lib array in the tsconfig.json file in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, config

In my Angular 6 project, in tsconfig.json and ts.config.spec.json I have this part:

```
"lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
```

What is `dom` for?

Official documentation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#including-built-in-type-declarations-with---lib) says: "... you can exclude declarations you do not want to include in your project, e.g. DOM if you are working on a node project using --lib es5,es6."

But I am not sure what this means in practice. We do not specify "any declarations you do not want."

My tests were totally broken until I added `dom` to the `lib` array in tsconfig.spec.ts. What does this do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`dom` lib is a set of JavaScript Web API interfaces, including DOM, DOM Events, Audio, Canvas, Video, XHR API... You can see full source code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts)

Of course you should include this library if you are developing frontend web. For backend Node.js development, it is optional. However, there is some Node.js package that is used for both frontend and backend. And you will meet type missing error when compiling without including it

Comment: Yes, before I added this `dom` to `tsconfig.json`, when I tried running tests I had a bunch of errors like `Cannot find name 'FormData'` or `Cannot find name 'window'` and a lot of similar ones. Is it because those names that were not found are included in `dom` interfaces? And therefore when `dom` was not added, it was broken?

Comment: Yes. Main advantage of TypeScript over JavaScript is it check type error for you. So if any type is missing, the error will show while compiling.